# how to update json array value at run-time in Karate

Tags: testing, karate

I am calling a getAPI and storing the response in jsonRequest like below.

- def jsonRequest = response

This jsonRequest will have the clientIds property/attribute which is of array type as below and It might have null, single or multiple values.

"clientIds": [
1
],

I need to set the value to 1 only if clientIds is having null as below otherwise I do not want to update this attribute. how to achieve this in karate

"clientIds": [
null
],

I tried below options.

1. `* def clientIdvalue = response.clientIds[0] == null ? 1 : response.clientIds`
2. `* if (jsonRequest.clientIds[0] == null) * set jsonRequest.clientIds[0] = 1`

And set jsonRequest

```
  | path             | values                                   |
 | clientIds[0]     | clientIdvalue                       |
```

It sets the client value as below instead of the actual values.

```
"clientIds": [
    "#ref:net.minidev.json.JSONArray"
  ],
```

Question 2:

And set jsonRequest

```
 | path             | values                                   |
 | clientIds[0]     | clientIdvalue                       |
```

This will set only the value at Index 0, how to set the whole array if there are multiple values.

Comment: ask one question at a time please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `set` and "normal" JS is easier:

```
* def data = { clientIds: [ null ] }
* if (data.clientIds.length == 1 && data.clientIds[0] == null) data.clientIds = [ 1 ]
* match data == { clientIds: [ 1 ] }
```